# how to display corresponding data to datagridview from selected item in listbox?

Tags: c#, mysql, listbox

I'm trying to display a corresponding data to my datagridview upon selecting an item (data fetch from database) from a listbox control. But i'm stuck in the portion where my string variable value is a concatenated string of multiple tables in the database. But when i trying to use a single database column for the string though it works well.

The following codes below provide all the details. 
When I'm trying to use a single database column for the string "selectdlst" under this `lstbox_doc_pat_opd.Items.Add(mysqlconstring.reader["hopdlog.licno"].ToString());` it works well, but when using `lstbox_doc_pat_opd.Items.Add(mysqlconstring.reader["Doctors"].ToString());` it will return null due to being a concatenated column.   .

```
    private void lstbox_doc_pat_opd_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LOAD_REGISTERED_PAT_TO_TABLE();
    }


    private void LOAD_DOCTORS_IN_LISTBOX()
    {

        mysqlconstring.conn.Open();
        string dtc = _datetime_pat_reg.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        string query201 = "SELECT  CONCAT(hpersonal.firstname, '  ', hpersonal.lastname) AS 'Doctors', hopdlog.licno AS 'License No.' FROM hopdlog INNER JOIN hprovider ON hprovider.licno=hopdlog.licno INNER JOIN hpersonal ON  hpersonal.employeeid=hprovider.employeeid WHERE DATE(opddate) = @Datecurr GROUP BY hopdlog.licno ";

        mysqlconstring.cmd = mysqlconstring.conn.CreateCommand();
        mysqlconstring.cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        mysqlconstring.cmd.CommandText = query201;
        mysqlconstring.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Datecurr", dtc);
        mysqlconstring.reader = mysqlconstring.cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (mysqlconstring.reader.Read())
        {
                lstbox_doc_pat_opd.Items.Add(mysqlconstring.reader["Doctors"].ToString());        
        }

        mysqlconstring.conn.Close();
    }

    private void LOAD_REGISTERED_PAT_TO_TABLE()
    {
        mysqlconstring.conn.Open();
        string dtc = _datetime_pat_reg.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        string selectdlst = lstbox_doc_pat_opd.SelectedItem.ToString();
        string query201A = "select CONCAT(hperson.patlast, ',  ', hperson.patfirst, '  ',hperson.patmiddle) as 'Patient Name', hopdlog.hpercode as 'Hospital Number', hopdlog.tacode as 'Type of Service', hopdlog.tscode as 'Payment Type' from hopdlog INNER JOIN hperson ON hopdlog.hpercode=hperson.hpercode inner join hprovider ON hprovider.licno=hopdlog.licno inner join hpersonal ON  hpersonal.employeeid=hprovider.employeeid   where DATE(opddate) = @Datecurr AND hopdlog.licno ='" + selectdlst + "'";

        mysqlconstring.cmd = mysqlconstring.conn.CreateCommand();
        mysqlconstring.cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        mysqlconstring.cmd.CommandText = query201A;
        mysqlconstring.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Datecurr", dtc);
        mysqlconstring.adapt.SelectCommand = mysqlconstring.cmd;
        DataTable datble = new DataTable();
        mysqlconstring.adapt.Fill(datble);
        dgtable_doc_pat_opd.DataSource = datble;

        mysqlconstring.conn.Close();
    }
```

Comment: The DGV doesn't automatically repaint so you need to set to null : dgtable_doc_pat_opd.DataSource = null; dgtable_doc_pat_opd.DataSource = datble;

Comment: You need to use a Join when selecting more than one table.  See http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-join/

Comment: I used INNER JOIN based from my queries

Comment: the dgtable_doc_pat_opd.DataSource = datble; does work when my datareader in listbox control is 
 set to "License" instead of the "Doctors" string lstbox_doc_pat_opd.Items.Add(mysqlconstring.reader["Doctors"].ToString());

Comment: How many columns are in the listbox?  License is not in the SQL query so I'm not sure if the issue is with the sql query or the values in the listbox.

Comment: From here: string query201 = "SELECT  CONCAT(hpersonal.firstname, '  ', hpersonal.lastname) AS 'Doctors', hopdlog.licno AS 'License No.'  Sorry, it was 'License No.'  When i use the License No. Column it does work, but when i use the Doctors column it returns null.

Comment: The listbox control when retreiving the data: lstbox_doc_pat_opd.Items.Add(mysqlconstring.reader["Doctors"].ToString());

Comment: You have two tables 1) hpersonal 2) hopdlog.  So the join is probably not working.  I suspect if you reverse the order of the join and put the hpersonal before the hopdlog you would get the doctor and not the license.